I am taking error= ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
I tried to make this code based on the source code below, I want to get the URLs, but the code didn't work.
Can you please help me find the error?
**code**
!pip install DuckDuckGoImages

import DuckDuckGoImages as ddg

def search_images(term, max_images,license=ddg.ALL, safe_search=True):
  print(f"Searching for '{term}'")
  urls=ddg.get_image_urls(term,license, safe_search)
  return urls[:max_images]
search_images('cow',10)

error:
Searching for 'cow'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-0a343959ad48> in <cell line: 5>()
      3   urls=ddg.get_image_urls(term,license, safe_search)
      4   return urls[:max_images]
----> 5 search_images('cow',10)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/DuckDuckGoImages.py in _fetch_search_urls(q, token, license, safe_search, URL, what)
    134 
    135     urls = []
--> 136     _urls, next = _get_urls(f"{URL}i.js", query, what)
    137     urls.extend(_urls)
    138     while next is not None:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)```



**source code**

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/DuckDuckGoImages.py:



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
